# Ошибка сегментации при размерности двумерного массива. Метод Дейкстры (C++)

Tags: c++, матрицы, segmentation-fault

Программа для поиска кратчайшего пути в графе методом Дейкстры. При выполнении максимально возможное число ребер 100х100, при дальнейшем увеличении этого числа программа выдает ошибку сегментации.
При запуске вводим количество вершин и количество ребер, создается квадратная матрица и заполняется случайными данными.

Компилирую на университетском кластере при помощи следующей команды:
`mpicxx -o test1.out Lab1.cpp -std=c++11`
Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

class Timer
{
private:
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using second_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> >;

    chrono::time_point<clock_t> m_beg;

public:
    Timer() : m_beg(clock_t::now())
    {
    }

    double elapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_t>(clock_t::now() - m_beg).count();
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a,c;
    cout << "Enter the number of vertices: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the number of ribs : ";
    cin >> c;
    long int **v = (long int **) malloc(c * sizeof(long int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            v[i] = (long int *) malloc(c * sizeof(long int));
    }   
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            v[i][j] = v[j][i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
        v[i][0] = v[0][i] = 0;
    }

    bool visit[100];
    int distance[100];
    string path[100];

    Timer t;

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        visit[i] = false;
        distance[i] = INT_MAX;
    }

    distance[1] = 0;
    visit[1] = true;

    queue<int>q;

    q.push(1);
    path[1] = to_string(1);

    while (!q.empty()) {
        int vert = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (int j = 1; j < sizeof(v[vert]); j++) {
            if (!visit[j] && v[vert][j] && v[vert][j] + distance[vert] < distance[j]) {
                distance[j] = v[vert][j] + distance[vert];
                path[j] = path[vert] + "-" + to_string(j);
                q.push(j);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Shortest Path Output: \n" << endl;

    for (int j = 2; j < a + 1; j++) {
        cout << "Distance to " << j << " vertex = " << distance[j] << endl;
        cout << "Path to " << j << " vertex: " << path[j] << "\n\n";
    }


    cout << "Time elapsed: " << t.elapsed() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логично, что программа падает. У Вас есть такие массивы

```
bool visit[100];
int distance[100];
string path[100];
```

как раз 100:) я увеличил до 1000 все три числа и теперь при 200 работает как нужно (я надеюсь).

Также, освобождайте память или используйте обычный `vector<vector<long int>>`